# How to deploy a grails binary plugin to artifactory with jenkins?

Tags: maven, grails, groovy, jenkins, artifactory

I want to publish a binary grails plugin to my artifactory repository with jenkins.

The process should be: GIT Push -> Jenkins Build -> Deploy in artifactory

I just tested it with the artifactory jenkins plugin but couldn't get it working because after the plugin deploys the jar i can't resolve it with my main grails application because the jar gets deployed without artifactId, groupId and so on.

How can i get this working? How is this done right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [Grails Release Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/release).  It allows you to [publish](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-release/docs/manual/guide/single.html#configuration) to private maven-compatible plugin repositories.

You can specify the location of your artifactory repo in BuildConfig.groovy:

```
grails.project.repos.myRepo.url = "http://my-artifactory/repos"
grails.project.repos.default = "myRepo"
```

Then you can use the command `grails publish-plugin` to deploy to your artifactory.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, i could deploy my plugin to my repository (binary plugin) but now i can't get it working with my main app. Using the plugin as inplace plugin works, using as depdendency resolves the plugin fine but doesn't work.